# Sync Framework Confusion

Tags: synchronization, compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm new in synchronization work. I am confused that:

If I synced 10 rows first time, then add 10 more rows and sync them again, then Sync
framework will sync the whole 20 rows again??

And if it syncs only newly added 10 rows, then how does it come to know about new rows and already synced rows??

I searched it, but could not get any relevant answer. Anyone please explain it. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

sync fx will only sync incremental changes or changes that occurred after the last sync.

in your first scenario, its should only sync the 10 new rows on next sync.

the second scenario is the actual behavior.

Sync fx does change tracking to keep track of changes that occurs to the table being synched (insert/update/delete). it also records an anchor/marker when it last synched so it knows it should only be retrieving changes that are later than that anchor/marker.

Comment: can we see that track of changes??

Comment: Look for tables with the suffix '_tracking'

Comment: there is not any record..they are empty.

Comment: Even sometime am facing a problem like once I've synced some rows, then next I add more rows and synced them again, but this time sync does not work. It does not show any error on synchronization but it does not sync any record. I dont know why its happening.

Comment: how are you adding rows? the _tracking tables are populated by triggers everytime you insert/update/delete. Subscribe to the ApplyChangeFailed event on your sync providers and you should if there's an error or a conflict applying a change

Comment: I've WPF application, in which am taking data from user, and then add them to the databse. I've subscribed that event but there's no any error caught by it.

Comment: Post the code on how you're adding rows. If the tracking tables are not being populated when you add rows, the triggers are not firing. Are you using bulk inserts?

Comment: Sorry for late,, no its not bulk insert, its simple single row insertion and then after particular time, i call sync..